# How to add a unique number for each reiteration and render it multiple times?

Tags: count

I am working on a testimonial slider and each slide is wrapped in an `<li>` tag. The JS looks for a similar id number, one for each layer of the slide, in this case I need to change the 1 in the example below.

Example:

"rs-1"
id="slide-1-layer-2" 
id="slide-1-layer-3"

I loop through the entries with a normal {% for %}{% endfor %} statement and I tried rendering the required number (1) with the {{ loop.index }} but I guess you can only use this once...

Is there a method do this? Perhaps with Twig?

If I am not clear this is what the result should be:

```
<li>"rs-1"
        id="slide-1-layer-2" 
        id="slide-1-layer-3" 
</li>
<li>"rs-2"
        id="slide-2-layer-2" 
        id="slide-2-layer-3" 
</li>
<li>"rs-3"
        id="slide-3-layer-2" 
        id="slide-3-layer-3" 
</li>
```

etc...

Comment: Nutmeg, I think the answer below is correct or do you still have issues with something?

Comment: yes, thank you Jan! Next is to use this in a sum, but i am sure thats done with a Twig native tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set it as a variable inside your loop and you can reuse it all you want.

```
 {% for entry in craft.entries.section('yourSection') %}
    {% set loopIndex = loop.index %}
    <li>"rs-{{loopIndex}}" id="slide-{{loopIndex}}-layer-2"</li>
 {% endfor %}
```